# Redirect cart button to Checkout - Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a simple code that redirects the customer directly to the "checkout" after adding to the cart.

```
add_filter('add_to_cart_redirect', 'cw_redirect_add_to_cart');
function cw_redirect_add_to_cart() {
   global $woocommerce;
   $cw_redirect_url_checkout = $woocommerce->cart->get_checkout_url();
   return $cw_redirect_url_checkout;
}
```

But I'm struggling a bit with how I can redirect the cart button on the top right side of the e-shop. If the customer clicks on the cart, they should be redirected to checkout.

I wanted to assign the checkout cart page in the Woo settings, but I don't see the page there because it's already been used once. So I would like to solve this by adding a code. I haven't found any solution that addresses this button directly.

Would you be able to advise me how to do this?

Comment: how is the button added "on the top right side of the e-shop"?

Comment: @CornelRaiu Automatically with the Woo plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to replace the cart URL with the checkout URL by using the filters WooCommerce provides.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_init', 'so_77294197_replace_cart_url' );
function so_77294197_replace_cart_url() {
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_redirect', function() {
        return wc_get_checkout_url();
    });

    add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_cart_url', function() {
        return wc_get_checkout_url();
    });
}
```

I haven't tested this, but it should work.

Comment: @ChadDavis if this helped you, you should upvote and mark the answer as accepted. That way others will know this is a viable solution. Thanks!